# Combine matching columns from two files, or use default value

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I am trying to rewrite a file text, *main.txt* with changes from *changes.txt*. The *main.txt* file is like this:

```
word_1 genre_A
word_2 genre_A
word_3 genre_B
word_4 genre_C
word_5 genre_A
```

And the *changes.txt* is like this:

```
genre_A root_A
genre_C root_C
```

I would like to change the ones that are in *changes.txt* in *main.txt* to obtain something like this:

```
word_1 root_A
word_2 root_A
word_3 genre_B
word_4 root_C
word_5 root_A
```

These files are really large, so I need an automatic method.

I tried to load all the variables from *changes.txt* in an `awk` array, and later print the same it was if it is different, and change if it is same.  Something like this:

```
NR==FNR{a[$1,$2]++;next}  $3==a[$1] {print $1,$2,a[$2]} $3!=a[$1] {print $1,$2,$3}
```

But I am doing something wrong. I also hear this can be done with the `join` command, but I am not used to that, so would be helpful to explain each part.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {if ($2 in a) print $1,a[$2]; else print $1,$2}' changes.txt main.txt
```

Output:

```
word_1 root_A
word_2 root_A
word_3 genre_B
word_4 root_C
word_5 root_A
```

Comment: @dr01, there's no need to _unwrap_ the code.

Comment: @agc IMHO, wrapping makes the code less easy to read.

Comment: @dr01 - some people might disagree with you... if you want to make it _"easier to read"_  just golf it shorter: `awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {if ($2 in a) $2=a[$2]};1' changes.txt main.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the `join` command, but in this case it's not easy to use it. At least not by itself.

Let's try to join the two files. To do that, the files first need to be sorted on the join field.  We are going to be using the second field from the first file and the first field (which is the default for `join`) from the second file:

```
$ sort -k2 -o main.txt main.txt
$ sort -k1 -o changes.txt changes.txt
```

Then we do the join:

```
$ join -1 2 main.txt changes.txt
genre_A word_1 root_A
genre_A word_2 root_A
genre_A word_5 root_A
genre_C word_4 root_C
```

We're missing one line.  Try again and tell `join` to also output lines from `main.txt` that would otherwise be left out (because they don't match anything in `changes.txt`):

```
$ join -1 2 -a 1 main.txt changes.txt
genre_A word_1 root_A
genre_A word_2 root_A
genre_A word_5 root_A
word_3 genre_B
genre_C word_4 root_C
```

Notice that we can't ask `join` to output only some of the columns from either file because the second column in the wanted output contains a mix of data from both files.

However, with the output above, we may extract the last two columns using a simple `awk` script (I so wish `cut` could take negative field specifications to get columns from the right!):

```
$ join -1 2 -a 1 main.txt changes.txt | awk '{ print $(NF-1), $NF }'
word_1 root_A
word_2 root_A
word_5 root_A
word_3 genre_B
word_4 root_C
```

Pipe this to `sort` for sorting:

```
$ join -1 2 -a 1 main.txt changes.txt | awk '{ print $(NF-1), $NF }' | sort
word_1 root_A
word_2 root_A
word_3 genre_B
word_4 root_C
word_5 root_A
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sort** and **join** (but no *awk*) method:

```
sort -k2    main.txt >    main_sort.txt ; \
sort -k1 changes.txt > changes_sort.txt ; \
{ join      -i  -1 2 -2 1  -o 1.1 2.2  main_sort.txt changes_sort.txt ; \
  join -v 1 -i  -1 2 -2 1  -o 1.1 1.2  main_sort.txt changes_sort.txt ; } | \
  sort -g | column -t
```

Output:

```
word_1  root_A
word_2  root_A
word_3  genre_B
word_4  root_C
word_5  root_A
```

---

Explanation...

`join` requires two files with sorted fields.  Since each file is large and needs to be used twice, it's more efficient to sort both files in advance.  Assume all files are *tab* delimited.

Sort *main.txt* by the *2nd* field (genre), and *changes.txt* by the *1st* field (root):

```
sort -k2    main.txt >    main_sort.txt
sort -k1 changes.txt > changes_sort.txt
```

Pass 1, output the lines with matches:

```
join -i -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 2.2 main_sort.txt changes_sort.txt
```

Which outputs 4 lines, sorted by the *root* field:

```
word_1 root_A
word_2 root_A
word_5 root_A
word_4 root_C
```

The `join` flags *"-1 2 -2 1"* tell it to *join* the **1st** file's *second* field to the **2nd** file's *first* field.  The flags *"-o 1.1 2.2"* tell it to *print* the **1st** file's *first* field to the **2nd** file's *second* field.

Pass 2, use the *"-v 1"* flag to output the missing line from the *first* file:

```
join -v 1 -i -1 2 -2 1  -o 1.1 1.2  main_sort.txt changes_sort.txt
```

Output:

```
word_3 genre_B
```

After which the outputs of both are combined, then sorted, (see top of answer).

Comment: Using `bash` allows dispensing with the extra set of files, but if the files are *huge*, the sorting time might well **double**:  `{ join -i -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 2.2 <(sort -k2 main.txt) <(sort -k1 changes.txt) ; join -v 1  -i -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 <(sort -k2 main.txt) <(sort -k1 changes.txt) ; } | sort -g | column -t`, (since each file would be sorted *twice*.)